# Compound Interest Formula adding annual contributions

Tags: finance

I'd like to know the compound interest formula for the following scenario:

P = Initial Amount
i = yearly interest rate
A = yearly contribution or deposit added.
n = the deposits will be made for 10 consecutive years.
F = final amount obtained.

I start with an initial amount and an yearly interest rate applied will be applied to it. Then, every year a contribution/deposit is made at the end of the period, that is, after the interest is applied to the previous amount.  No withdrawals are made.

Comment: Have you tried simply using small values for $n$ and modelling the situation?  WIth yearly interest, the interest is only applied once, along with the contribution...

Comment: I need the formula for a school project, that is why I made it yearly.  I do know the final amount I get by using online bank calculators, but I still need to get the actual formula.

Answer (score 10):

The final value $F=F'+F''$ is the sum of two components:

- the initial deposit will produce after $n$ years at the interest rate $i$ the future value
  $$F'=P(1+i)^n$$
- the periodic payments are an annuity-immediate (made at the end of each contribution period) the future value is
  $$
  F''=A\,s_{\overline{n}|i}=A\frac{(1+i)^n-1}{i}
  $$
  Thus, the future value $F$ is
  $$
  F=P(1+i)^n+A\frac{(1+i)^n-1}{i}=\left(P+\frac{A}{i}\right)(1+i)^n-\frac{A}{i}
  $$
  If the additional payments are made at the beginning of each period the annuity is an annuity due and the future value is obtained multiplying by $(1+i) $, that is
  $$
  F''=A\frac{(1+i)^n-1}{i}(1+i)
  $$
  and then 
  $$
  F=P(1+i)^n+A\frac{(1+i)^n-1}{i}(1+i) =\left(P+\frac{A}{d}\right)(1+i)^n-\frac{A}{d}
  $$
  where $ d=\frac{i}{1+i} $ is the discount rate.

Comment: The number I get is close, but smaller than the one on this site
http://www.bankrate.com/calculators/savings/compound-savings-calculator-tool.aspx

Comment: This is what I got from entering some numbers.
http://i.imgur.com/8Y7WfEa.jpg?1

Comment: That's because the web calculator considers the additional payments made at the beginning of each contribution period not at the end as you stated.

Comment: How would be the formula if the additional contributions were made at the beginning of each year?.  Thanks.

Comment: I added it in my answer  (last equation )

Comment: @alexjo , these formulas explode when the interest rate is 0. Do you have any thoughts on how to avoid that problem? Thanks!

Comment: Actually for $i=0$ you have $F'=P $  and $F''=nA $ an then $F=P+nA $.

Answer (score 6):

See if this helps...

So year 1; I have my initial deposit of $P$.  First I need to compute the interest gained and then I have to add the new yearly contribution $A$.  So by year $1$ I have

$$F_1=P+Pi+A=P(1+i)+A$$

where $F_t$ is the total in the account after $t$ years.  Now that new amount will accrue yearly interest, and then you have to add $A$ to that...

$$F_2=[P(1+i)+A]+[P(1+i)+A]i+A=[P(1+i)+A](1+i)+A$$
$$=P(1+i)^2+A(1+i)+A$$

After year 3, doing the same calculation will yield for year 3

$$F_3=P(1+i)^3+A(1+i)^2+A(1+i)+A$$

$$=P(1+i)^3+A\sum_{k=0}^2(1+i)^k$$

Note that the sum is geometric and yields the formula

$$A\sum_{k=0}^2(1+i)^k=\frac{A(1+i)^3-A}{(1+i-1)}=\frac{A(1+i)^3-A}{i}$$

Thus we can extrapolate and see that for 10 years our formula is

$$F_{10}=P(1+i)^{10}+\frac{A(1+i)^{10}-A}{i}$$
which can be reduced like @alexjo did in his using annuity formulas as

$$\left(P+\frac{A}{i}\right)(1+i)^{10}-\frac{A}{i}$$

Comment: Indeed, I can continue from the F3 function on, but what is the shorter expression of final formula?.

Comment: I amended the question to include the final answer... it is the same as @alexjo's

Comment: Thanks.   However, I don't seem to get the same result when using this bank rate calculator
http://www.bankrate.com/calculators/savings/compound-savings-calculator-tool.aspx

Comment: @user3323679 This is a rather late reply but that is probably because the answers here give a formula where another yearly contribution is added to the final amount, but the website you pointed to ends the yearly contribution the year before your final year.