# How to solve for n in compound interest + RD formula?

Tags: finance

Say at the start of every year 230 USD is deposited, and there's 15% interest compounded annually. I want to calculate how many years it would take to make 7,000 USD. I found a relevant formula [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1698634/), but I was unable to figure out how to alter it to solve for `n`.

Comment: So you just want to solve for $n$ ? I can get you started! We start with 
$$
F = \left(P+ \frac{A}{d} \right) \left(1+i \right)^n - \frac{A}{d}
$$
move the last term to the left-hand side, and divide by the first parenthesis ... 
$$
\frac{F +  \frac{A}{d}}{ \left(P+ \frac{A}{d} \right)   }  = \left(1+i \right)^n
$$
Do you know how to continue from here?

Comment: Nevermind I'm wrong, and no I don't.

Comment: Why do you say that you're wrong?

Comment: I made a mistaken comment and deleted it, but it appears I missed the deadline to edit.

Comment: I can give you a hint for the next step (after the second equation): Take a logarithm on both sides.

Comment: I tried doing that and got a very incorrect answer.

Comment: So what did you do, exactly, and what was the result? If you show it to me, I can correct it and tell you what went wrong.

Comment: I tried $log(1 + i)$ on both sides to isolate $n$.

Comment: When I said "take a logarithm on both sides", I meant this:
$$
\frac{F+A/d}{P+A/d} = (1+i)^n \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad \ln \frac{F+A/d}{P+A/d}  = \ln \left(  (1+i)^n \right) =  \ldots
$$

Comment: So at the end of my first comment, you basically have an equation of the form
$$
a^x = b
$$
to solve. Here $a=(1+i)$ and $b$ is the left-hand side of the equation. Have you solved equations like this before?

Comment: That question seems irrelevant so I'm just going to answer no, just assume the answer is no for any future parts as well.