# Compounding Interest formula adding increasing annual contributions

Tags: compound-interest

thank you for your time. I have a question about generating a formula similar to this question.

My question is, what would the formula look like if I wanted to contribute $10\%$ of my base salary of $\$90,000$ into an annuity that grows $2\%$ annually, but every year, my overall salary raises by $\$5000$

*** I'd like to know the compound interest formula for the following scenario:

P = Initial Amount i = yearly interest rate A = yearly contribution or deposit added. n = the deposits will be made for 10 consecutive years. F = final amount obtained.

I start with an initial amount and an yearly interest rate applied will be applied to it. Then, every year a contribution/deposit is made at the end of the period, that is, after the interest is applied to the previous amount. No withdrawals are made. ***

[Compound Interest Formula adding annual contributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1698578/compound-interest-formula-adding-annual-contributions)

Here is a link to the formulas.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/proposal-discourage-questions-that-are-nothing-besides-a-problem-statement), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) will help you recognize and resolve the issues.

Comment: The first contribution $\$9000$ grows for $n$ years, the second contribution $\$9500$ grows for $n-1$ years, ..., lastly the $n$th contribution $\$8500+\$500n$ grows for $1$ year. You can derive a formula for the Future Value as an [arithmetico-geometric sequence sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence#Sum_of_the_terms).

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).