# Return required to achieve Future Value using Compound Interest Formula with annual contributions

Tags: finance, compound-interest

Referring to the same formula from this [question (Compound Interest Formula adding annual contributions)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1698578/compound-interest-formula-adding-annual-contributions).

$$
F=P(1+i)^n+A\frac{(1+i)^n-1}{i}=\left(P+\frac{A}{i}\right)(1+i)^n-\frac{A}{i}
$$

where

```
P = Principle value
i = interest rate, annually
A = Annual amount contribution
n = duration in years
F = Future value
```

If all of the variables above is known, except `i`. How do we get the formula of `i`? I'm having trouble in getting the formula of `i`.

$$
i=?
$$

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of problem, as soon as $n>4$, there is no analytical solution since the problem would be to find the roots of a polynomial of degree $n$ on $i$.

So, either numerical methods or approximations.

For approximations, since $i$ is known to be small, use for example a series expansion, which would give
$$F-(P+A n)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \Bigg(A \binom{n}{k+1}+P \binom{n}{k}\Bigg)\,i^k$$

Using only the first term,it will provide a starting point for any numerical method such as Newton
$$i_0=\frac 2n\,\frac{F-(P+A n) }{(n-1)A+2P }$$

Using, for illustration : $F=2500$, $P=1000$, $A=100$ and $n=10$, this would give $i_0=\frac 1{29}=0.0344828$ while the solution is $i=0.0305279$.

Newton iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & i_k \\
 0 & 0.0344828 \\
 1 & 0.0305879 \\
 2 & 0.0305280 \\
 3 & 0.0305279 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

which is a quite fast convergence.

If you do not want to use numerical methods, let
$$B=F-(P+A n) \qquad \text{and} \qquad a_k=A \binom{n}{k+1}+P \binom{n}{k}$$ which make
$$B=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k\, i^k$$ Truncate to some order and use [power series reversion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html).

This would give
$$i \sim \frac 1{a_1}B-\frac {a_2}{a_1^3}B^2+\frac{2a_2^2 -a_1a_3}{a_1^5} B^3+\cdots$$ and you can use as many terms as you want.

Using the same numbers and the above very truncated series would give
$$i \sim \frac{629221}{20511149}=0.030677$$ Adding the next term would give $i=0.0304949$.

Comment: Isn't the degree of the polynomial $n+1$?